# How to send the Content-Length with the request in Apache JMeter?

Tags: java, http, jmeter, content-length, http-content-length

How to send the Http Content-Length header in Apache JMeterHttp Request?

I'm using Apache JMeter to send a get request to a configured endpoint, as shown in the following diagram.

[image]

There, I'm using the parameters tab to set the request parameters, However, JMeter doesn't send the content-length header to the server.

I checked this by printing the request in the server. Following is the server received request.

```
GET /io?Message=Nelika HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Host: localhost:4333
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_212)
```

How can I configure JMeter to send the content-length?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter doesn't send Content-Length on [GET Request](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/c7b9bb935e5e4e01cbc89b4fba6cd4db78d51f1d/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPHC4Impl.java) because it may be not expected:

> Some servers fail if Content-Length is equal to 0

For other methods, add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of your HTTP Request

Add row with name: `Content-Type` and value as: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Notice that you aren't sending any entity body in your GET request, thus it'll send 0 value

**EDIT**

A work around is to add to [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) row with Content-Length value (it'll be overridden)

Comment: I added the Content_Type in Http Header Manager. Then the server receives the content type as follows. 

    GET /io?Message=Nelika HTTP/1.1
    Connection: close 
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Host: localhost:4333
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_212

But what I want is to get the content length (the length of the get parameters)

Comment: @PasinduTennage try to send POST request with request body which will be more relevant to sending `Content-Length`

Comment: With post requests (even without request body), I get the content-length. Seems like JMeter does not send the Content-Length for GET Requests.

Comment: @PasinduTennage yes, you are right, this is because in GET request (quoted) *Some servers fail if Content-Length is equal to 0*  https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/c7b9bb935e5e4e01cbc89b4fba6cd4db78d51f1d/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPHC4Impl.java